# Error: Circular dependency - NestJS Testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

When I create a test of my controller I get the following error:

> A circular dependency has been detected. Please make sure that each
> side of a bidirectional relationship is decorated with "forwardRef()"

```
  // category.service.ts
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Category.name) private categoryModel: Model<CategoryDocument>,
    private readonly subcategoriesService: SubcategoriesService,
  ) {}


// category.controller.spec.ts
describe('V1CategoriesController', () => {
  let categoriesController: CategoriesController;
  let categoriesService: CategoriesService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [CategoriesController],
      providers: [CategoriesService, SubcategoriesService],
    }).compile();

    categoriesController = moduleRef.get<CategoriesController>(
      CategoriesController,
    );
    categoriesService = moduleRef.get<CategoriesService>(CategoriesService);
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('CategoriesController - should be defined', () => {
    expect(categoriesController).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

I tried to create a SubcategoriesService Mock, but I'm not sure it's the right way to do it

```
const SubcategoriesService = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  findByCategory: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([]),
});

const moduleRef: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [CategoriesController],
      providers: [CategoriesService, { provide: 'SubcategoriesService', useFactory: SubcategoriesService },],
    }).compile();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your main service you are using a Mock?
There is a possibility that you are not using a mock or it has the wrong name.

Comment: Yes, the name of the Mock was misspelled.